# Couchbase lite Android - no documents in bucket

Tags: android, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have downloaded **GrocerySync** (Android) and Run the app both on device and emulator It working as should be, sync working is fine.

But I have following doubts,

1)Where data is getting stored?How to check?

2)No data bucket is created (with given name) in Couchbase lite console,Do we need to create our  bucket manually?

Any help greatly appreciated.

3)Do I need to do any configuration so that data is is stored Couchbase lite,If so what configuration I have to do?

Comment: What is the "Couchbase lite console"?  Do you mean Sync Gateway?  There are two pieces : The local DB on the device, and the server storage that sync gateway writes to (usually Couchbase Sever in production, but can be a memory DB / flat file for testing).  It's hard to tell which you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

> 1)Where data is getting stored?How to check?

When you create document using your android app it gets stored in the CouchBase lite. It is a database embedded in the android app. For checking in the couchbase Lite I usually insert data and then get() the same data by using getId() function. I dont think there is any GUI for couchbase Lite.

Now if you have sync gateway configured then it stores the data in DB(after you give push request) you provided to sync gateway(can be walrus or couchbase server). For checking in DB you can directly use their respective GUI.

> 2)No data bucket is created (with given name) in Couchbase lite console,Do we need to create our bucket manually?

There is no bucket created in CouchBase Lite. Only database is created and you have to create the database. Check [this](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/training/build-first-android-app/starter-code-android/index.html) link on how to create a database and manager in couchbase Lite

> 3)Do I need to do any configuration so that data is is stored Couchbase lite,If so what configuration I have to do?

Check the above link on how to create databse and manager in CouchBase Lite. To perform CURD operations check [this](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/do-crud/index.html)